# ionic3 tabs layout, how to keep the state when ionic serve reload in chrome

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-cli

I use ionc3 with 'tabs layout', 'ionic serve', 'IonPageModule' for development, in chrome.

1. when I edit the  other component(not the first tab's root page ) and
   saved it. the browser  reload and always navigate to  the first
   tab's root page.
2. Although  there  is  a  url  for every page, reload the browser,the state can not be saved, the first tab's root page has been actived.

   If my app  has many pages, this is a really serious issue.

   [image: reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually not possible. After your modify your code and save, the live reload of Ionic behaves as if you restarted the application to take the new logical changes into account (note that .scss changes can be directly applied).

If you need to "save the state", you will need a database or use the storage.

Comment: thank you for your answer
but  if the app has many pages ,this is a really serious issue,since ionic give up angular router,.

Comment: Maybe I miss a point, but how is it a serious issue? When you are opening an app on your phone, you usually lands on some kind of "Home page". That is actually a pretty standard behavior.

Comment: I just open the app in browser, i just wanner webapp without cordova.
I develop the app  and preview in chrome.
So  this is a big issue for development and debug in browser.
Mybe this is a not cerrect way...

Comment: are you chinese ?   hah ,from you user name  'kai xin'  can translate to '开心'

Comment: Yes, we could say that's a limitation of debug in browser with Ionic. I have no better idea to help you.
And nope, French actually. But I do know Chinese :)

Comment: :)  your username  mean to ‘smile,happy’ in chinese

Comment: You're welcome ^^ You can mark the answer as accepted if you think it deserves it. And good luck for your dev :)